# Javascript While Loop exits before finishing execution

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a simple program:

Input: a date1

Output: a date2 that is 4 weekdays from date1 (going forward in time)

I execute the code and only receive a date2 that is 1 day away.
After some investigation, I noticed that my while loop is only executing once, not 4 times like I specified in `let freeDays = 4;`.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? Why is the `while` loop not going through 4 times?

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  this.setDate( this.getDate()  + days);
  return this;

Date.prototype.isWeekday = function(){
  return !((this.getDay() == 0)||(this.getDay() == 6));
}

function getLastFreeDay(date1){
  let freeDays = 4; 
  while (freeDays>0){
    if(date1.isWeekday()){
      freeDays--;
      date1.addDays(1);
    }
    else{
      date1.addDays(1);
    }
  return date1;
  }
}

console.log(getLastFreeDay(new Date(2022, 1, 22)))
```

Comment: your `return` is inside the `while` loop. It should be outside, just afterwards.

Comment: If you indent the code properly you would see this more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop ends on the first exection because you are returning `date1` inside it. `return date1` will return whatever the value of `date1` is up to that point (just before first loop iteration ends), and the function won't continue executing. So, even though the loop was suposed to continue, it was running inside the `getLastFreeDay` function scope, so it stops as well.

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller. [1]

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return